# How to apply filters together?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, google-maps-markers

I have markers on a Google Map with dropdown filters, and these filters work perfectly well individually. However, I want the filter to consider all three drop-down lists at once.

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/h4cv57tb/

Somehow the 3 filter functions should be merged, but unfortunately I have no idea how to ...

Here are the filter functions which should be merged:

```
//Filter by type
filterMarkers = function(category) {
                for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++) {
                    marker = gmarkers1[i];
                    // If is same category or category not picked
                    if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
                        marker.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    // Categories don't match
                    else {
                        marker.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }
    
            //FILTER by ripening time
    
            filterMarkersEres = function(eres) {
                for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++) {
                    marker = gmarkers1[i];
                    var ereshonap = marker.eres;
    
                    // If is same category or category not picked
                    if (ereshonap.includes(parseInt(eres)) || eres.length === 0) { //
                        marker.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    // Categories don't match
                    else {
                        marker.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }
    
    
            //FILTER by place
            filterMarkersHely_tipus = function(hely_tipus) {
                for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++) {
                    marker = gmarkers1[i];
                    // If is same category or category not picked
                    if (marker.hely_tipus == hely_tipus || hely_tipus.length === 0) {
                        marker.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    // Categories don't match
                    else {
                        marker.setVisible(false);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you look at where there is duplicate code and simply combine areas that are different, if feasible. To combine these functions into a single one just combine the if conditions together.

```
filterMarkers = function(category = null, eres = null, hely_tipus = null) {
    for (i = 0; i < gmarkers1.length; i++) {
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        ereshonap = marker.eres;
        visible = false;

        if (category){
            if (marker.category == category || category.length === 0) {
            visible = true;
            }
        }

        if (eres) {
            if (ereshonap.includes(parseInt(eres)) || eres.length === 0) {
            visible = true;
            }
        }

        if (hely_tipus) {
            if(marker.hely_tipus == hely_tipus) {
                visible = true;
            }
        }

        if (visible) {
            marker.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this before, but the problem is that the drop-down filters can only pass one parameter, so the function is waiting for three. So it doesn't work for me yet unfortunately ...

Comment: @walacky In that case add some default arguments to them as null and check if they are truthy before its actual check. That way it'll run even if an argument is not passed.

Comment: @walacky I have ammended the code with defaults.

Comment: and based on this, how can i modify my select's onchange event? Now it is: <select id="type" onchange="filterMarkers(this.value);">

Comment: @walacky I had a quick look at your code, if your doing for example filterMarkersEres, you'd do it like this `filterMarkers(null, this.value)` or `filterMarkers(null, this.value, null)`.

Comment: @walacky sorry just noticed the code wasn't working... fixed it.